# Django Celery test runner doing very strange things

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to test some celery functionality in my Django app, but I can't even get the basic testing system down.

When I follow what everything says and add `TEST_RUNNER = 'djcelery.contrib.test_runner.CeleryTestSuiteRunner'` to the bottom of my settings file, some unusual things happen when I try to test with `manage.py test`:

1)  A bunch of tests I never wrote seem to be run.  Previously, I had 18 tests that all passed.  Now, I run the tests and I get this:

```
................................................................................
.....................x..........................................................
...................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 227 tests in 0.802s

OK (expected failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

2)  My tests have currently been in a folder named `tests` within my app folder, with each file named, e.g., `test_models.py`.  However, upon adding the `CelerySuiteTestRunner`, none of those tests run at all - I can add failing tests and they don't fail.

3)  However, if I get rid of that folder and add a single `tests.py` file in the app folder, anything in that file *will* run.  (If I leave the `tests` folder in place, it will not run tests in the `tests.py` file.)

I'm just trying to add testing of my celery-related tasks to my app.  Can anybody explain what is going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Django 1.6, which [changed the default test runner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#discovery-of-tests-in-any-test-module). `CeleryTestSuiteRunner` inherits from Django's old `DjangoTestSuiteRunner`, which runs tests from all installed apps, including the apps provided with Django, but does not discover tests outside of the `tests` modules.

You could reimplement `CeleryTestSuiteRunner` in your own test runner using the new `DiscoverRunner` which will discover your tests as expected, e.g.:

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner
from djcelery.contrib.test_runner import _set_eager

class CeleryDiscoverRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def setup_test_environment(self, **kwargs):
        _set_eager()
        super(CeleryDiscoverRunner, self).setup_test_environment(**kwargs)
```

Comment: I assume you meant reimplement CeleryTestSuiteRunner (rather than DjangoTestSuiteRunner)?

In either case - it worked - thanks!  I definitely wouldn't have figured that one out.  Much appreciated! :)